# RSA decryption methodology

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm not learning cryptography yet, and this exercise - in the form it was delivered as a homework, was more of an exercise on reading composite functions and the like. Either way, I took a look at some part of the source code and didn't understand this.

For RSA encryption, the source code manipulated the string in such a way:

- Message is being hashed into an integer list. (int1, int2, int3...)
- Encrypt int1
- Subtract result from int2 ( int2 - e(int1))
- Modulo with the modulo key (n)
- RSA transform with a key.

However, the RSA decryption method is done by:

- 1) RSA_transform
- 2) Result is added
- 3) Modulo with n

---

The part that puzzles me about the RSA decryption is the need for modulo after the adding and rsa_transform. If it's needed, shouldnt it be used in reverse order of how the chain of operations was carried out in RSA encryption?

Also, an "invert_modulo" was provided in the source code. I originally believed this to be a key in decrypting the message, but it wasn't so. What could "invert_modulo" be used for?

Comment: You might be better off posting this question on: [http://crypto.stackexchange.com](http://crypto.stackexchange.com)

Comment: From your description it is really not clear what is happening in the source. What do you mean with "Message is being hashed"? I guess you are not talking about SHA256 etc. What happens in "Encrypt int1"? Is it the exponentiation modulo `n`: `int1^e mod n` where `e` is the public RSA exponent? How is it different from the "RSA transform with a key"? --- `invert_modulo` is likely [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse). In the context of RSA it is used in the key generation to calculated the private exponent `d` out of the public key (`e`,`n`) and `phi(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand the first part of your question as the steps to hash the string is not clear also i don't get 3rd part of your encryption step. As for the Second question invert_modulo is the "MODULAR MULTIPLICATIVE INVERSE".

While working with modular airthmetic we always want our answer to be in the integer range 0 to M-1(where M is the number we modulo with) simple operations like addition , multiplication and subtraction are easy to perform : like (a+b) MOD M, it is well defined for the constraints of modular airthmetic.

Problem arises wen we try to divide : (a/b) MOD M

as you can see here a/b may not always always give an integer, therefore (a/b) does not lie in the integer range 0 to M-1. so to overcome this we try to find an inverse of b that we would rather multiply a with, i.e : (a*b_inverse) MOD M.

b_inverse can be defined as : (b*b_inverse) MOD M = 1.

i.e b_inverse is a number in the range 0 to M-1, which when multiplied with b, modulo M yields 1.

Note : also note that modular inverse of some numbers might not exist we can check that by  taking the GCD of M and the number concerned(in our example "b") if GCD is not equal to 1 the the modular inverse does not exist.